# Eigenvalues of the transformation of a SPSD matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
\begin{align}
A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
be such that $A = C^T C$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$. Let the eigenvalues of $C$ be $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Clearly, $A$ has eigenvalues $\vert \lambda_1 \vert^2$ and $\vert \lambda_2 \vert^2$. If $A$ is invertible, its inverse satisfies
\begin{align}
A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A} \begin{pmatrix} c & -b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
with eigenvalues $\frac{1}{\vert \lambda_1 \vert^2}$ and $\frac{1}{\vert \lambda_2 \vert^2}$.

Now the question is: can we make any statements about the spectrum of the matrix
\begin{align}
\tilde{A} = \begin{pmatrix} c & -b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
even when $A$ is not invertible ? I know that when it is invertible, the eigenvalues must be the same as those of $A$.

Comment: Your formula for the inverse does not generally hold, even if $A$ is invertible.  Also, you used the letter $A$ for both the matrix as a whole and for the upper-left block

Comment: Thanks, I made the appropriate changes. Why is the formula for the inverse not generally true ?

Comment: First of all, here's [a formula for the inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix that actually does work.  Since the matrix in question is symmetric we'd have $B = C^T$.

Comment: Second, off the top of my head I think this should be a counterexample for the formula that you guessed:
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&0&0&1\\0&2&1&0\\0&1&3&0\\1&0&0&4}
$$

Comment: Note that if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and if they commute, I believe that the formula
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\B^T&C}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(AC - BB^T)} \pmatrix{C&-B\\-B^T&A}
$$ 
does hold.

Comment: $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ and $a,b,c$ are scalar.

Comment: I was still addressing the original version of your problem

Comment: it also says $A = C^T C$ with $C \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: If eigenvalues of $C$ are $\lambda_i$, it isn't necessarily true that eigenvalues of $C^TC$ are $|\lambda_i|^2$. As a counter example select $C=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. It is true if $C$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

You matrix $\tilde A$ is called the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_formula) of the matrix $A$.  Note in particular that we have
$$
\operatorname{adj}(\tilde A) = \operatorname{tr}(A)I - A = (a+c)I - A.
$$
It follows that if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then the eigenvalues of $\tilde A$ will be equal to 
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A) - \lambda_1 = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) - \lambda_1 = \lambda_2\\
\operatorname{tr}(A) - \lambda_2 = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) - \lambda_2 = \lambda_1.
$$
In other words, $\tilde A$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$, even in the case where $A$ fails to be invertible.  Note that the same will not be true about the adjugate matrix for larger matrices.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ are the same because they have the same characteristic polynomial.